# Computer is sending / receiving data form a computer and I don't know why

Tags: networking, wireshark

So I have been playing with WireShark and I have found something weird.

After closing every application that uses the internet (As far as I know) I have found that my computer is sending / receiving data from an IP address and I have no idea why.

As far as I know I have closed every application that might need the internet.

This is an image of my activity monitor and an image of what WS brings up.

[image]
[image]

I notice that Activity Monitor differs from the currently running processes.

Anyways. What can I do to understand the kind of info my computer is sending / receiving and why?

Also, I am kind of a Noob at WireShark and networking. So bear that in mind. (I am a web developer)

Comment: Which one of these entries is the one you're concerned about?

Comment: Check whether the communication attempts to IP 216.144.236.234 are legitimate.

Comment: This is what we have [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for, so we know who's asking to phone home. That IP address is quadranet.com in California - some kind of hosting solution... which really tells us little

Comment: Try selecting one of those UDP packets from port 8080 and using the "Decode As" menu item under "Analyze" to decode it as HTTP (yes, you can run HTTP over UDP) and see what that shows.

Answer (score 3):

Your operating system and installed programs have plenty of things to do when you're not using them. Like checking for updates, looking for other computers in LAN, syncing clock, checking mail, checking news, etc.

Yes, you will see lots of traffic, even when you're not clicking anything. That is expected.

Comment: It seemed awfully constant thought. And is there a way for me to know what it is? Is it voluntary?
Can I look inside of the packets in a way that makes sense? ( I suppose that depends if they are encrypted? )

Comment: @bezzoon People spend their lives learning to tell legitimate traffic from illegitimate one. And they make a living off those skills. There is no simple answer to your question, just as there is no answer to "how do I build a car".